# Creating pandas column based on threshold values in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like this where the distCum field indicates distance:

```
oid     distCum
1472    0
1473    0.084116923
1565    0.157785132
1469    2.326473679
9567    4.156309659
1500    5.953545907
9544    6.157304401
1561    6.190537806
8823    7.503586809
4037    8.547562197
```

The dataframe has millions of rows and the distCum column values indicates cumulative kms and increments to more than 1000 kms.  I am trying to create a cluster where every two kms are grouped together.  The desired output is as follows:

```
oid     distCum     Clust
1472    0           1
1473    0.084116923 1
1565    0.157785132 1
1469    2.326473679 2
9567    4.156309659 3
1500    5.953545907 3
9544    6.157304401 4
1561    6.190537806 4
8823    7.503586809 4
4037    8.547562197 5
```

To elaborate on the cluster classification, if the distance is

```
< 2 - cluster = 1
between 2 and 4 cluster = 2
between 4 and 6 cluster = 6
```

I tried using a for loop iterating over each column and however failing on applying the increment values for the divisor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.floordiv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.floordiv.html) with add `1` and casting to integers:

```
df['Clust'] = df['distCum'].floordiv(2).add(1).astype(int)
print (df)
    oid   distCum  Clust
0  1472  0.000000      1
1  1473  0.084117      1
2  1565  0.157785      1
3  1469  2.326474      2
4  9567  4.156310      3
5  1500  5.953546      3
6  9544  6.157304      4
7  1561  6.190538      4
8  8823  7.503587      4
9  4037  8.547562      5
```

Comment: Thanks a ton....I was stunned by your earlier answer...facepalm.  This work perfectly.